# jQuery show hidden menu

Tags: jquery, menu, navigation, hide, show

I have a small problem.

I've got a menu where all `<li>` has to be hidden, but if the class is set to active the `<li>` should reveal it's children ( `<ul>` )

The parent title and link should still be hidden, but the children should be shown.
This is NOT an onClick event thing.

The HMTL:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="active"><a href="#link1">TITLE</a>   <-- hidden
        <ul>                                        <-- showing
            <li><a href="#sublink1">TITLE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#sublink2">TITLE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#sublink3">TITLE</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#link2">TITLE</a></li>             <-- hidden
    <li><a href="#link3">TITLE</a></li>             <-- hidden
    <li><a href="#link4">TITLE</a>                  <-- hidden
        <ul>                                        <-- hidden
            <li><a href="#sublink1">TITLE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#sublink2">TITLE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#sublink3">TITLE</a></li>
        </ul>
</ul>
```

Any ideas how to make this in jQuery?

Comment: When do you want all this to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if parent is hidden the child will be it too. Even though its `display:block;`  to show both you could use

```
$('.active').each(function() {
     $(this).toggle();
     $(this).find('ul').toggle();
});
```

Comment: I know that. That's why i only want to hide the link and the title - not the list-element it self.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to your title links like so:

```
<a class='active-title'> TITLE </a>
```

then when you add the active class to your `<li>` do:

```
$(".active .title").hide();
$(".active ul").show();
```

If you don't want to add a class, you can use:

```
$(".active > a").hide();
$(".active ul").show();
```